# How can I change django model field value automatically with method?

Tags: python, django, api, graphql, backend

```
class AssignedTask(Task):
deadline = models.DateField()
amount = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
priority = models.FloatField()

def priority_set(self):
    delta = self.deadline - timezone.now().date()
    self.priority = delta.days / self.importance
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

I want to set a value of the 'priority' field when data AssignedTask is created, but the priority field always returns null when I create data with a mutation in graphQL API.

Comment: Are you sure you need this as a field? It would be better to keep it as a method, so you can call it when you need to display the value.

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite the save method

```
def save(self):
    self.priority_set()
    super().save()
```